# How can I create a state snapshot of my android device?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, backup, samsung-galaxy-note-2

I had restored my Android device (Samsung Note2) to the factory settings.

i have now added all my favorits apps and customized my settings.

How can i create a "memoey image"/"state snapshot" to restore from in the future.

I have used Kies, but it backups everything besides installed apps and device settings.

In generagl it's not creating a perfect snapshot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to use adb backup which is takes a complete backup of the phone.

You'll need to install the [Android SDK](https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) but this should allow you to backup the whole device

**Backup**

There are a number of parameters you can supply but the simplest way to do a full backup is to run: `adb backup -all -f C:\backup.ab`

More info can be found on this [xda post](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1420351) which although it uses a Galaxy Nexus it should apply to any 4.0+ device

**Restore**

With your device connected open your command prompt again, and type:

```
adb restore C:\backup20111230.ab
```

replacing 'C:\backup20111230.ab' with the location of your backup file.

You should see a screen like the one below:

[image: [Screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/WYaffus.png?1)]

Simply type in your current encryption password (if you've set one), and the password with which the backup was encrypted (if you chose to set a password), and the restore will begin. It again will take several minutes depending on the size of the backup and the options chosen.

Comment: will this include sound settings and so?

Comment: and then, how to restore?

Comment: I've added restore details. It should backup sound settings but I've not tried it myself so can't be sure.

Answer (score 0):

These kind of snapshots are impossible without root access to the device. If that condition is met, simply follow-up to the [backup tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/backup/info), everything is described there already (watch out for "Nandroid"):

[nandroid](/questions/tagged/nandroid) usually is integrated with custom recoveries (see also: [recovery-menu](/questions/tagged/recovery-menu)). It creates images of all your device's [partition](/questions/tagged/partition)s. As your device is not in "operative mode" when this is done, this results in a "consistent system snapshot" as you describe in your question. Those images can later be restored from within the very same recovery menu.